# php laravel 6 blade template

Tags: php, laravel, blade

Изучаю laravel 6 и постоянно возникает проблема с blade template.

Не работают в темплейте:
`@csrf, @error("name") $message @enderror, @method("patch")`, хотя такие конструкции как 
`@foreach, @forelse и @if` работают без проблем.

Вместо этого использую `{{ csrf_field() }}, @foreach($errors->all() as error) {$error} @endforeach` соответственно.

Если`@error("name") $message @enderror` выдаёт ошибку:

> Undefined variable: message, то @csrf и @method("patch")

просто выводятся в html как обычный текст. Сейчас возникла проблема с `@method("patch")`. Работаю на windows 7, open server пишу всё по документации, но приходится искать другой способ написания кода. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: покажите конкретно контроллер и метод, который отрисовывает шаблон, сам код шаблона. Вы шаблоны точно  `NAME.blade.php` называете?

Comment: Без контроллера и view не разобраться, добавьте пожалуйста!)

Answer (score 0):

```
Здесь ситуация с @error("name") {$message}. Вот контроллер.
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ServiceController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $var = 'create';

        return view('services.index', ['data' => $var, ]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
        $data = $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required'
        ]);
        $var = request('name');
        DB::table('services')->insert(['name' => $var]);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}


Вот темплейт в services/index.blade.php. Все темплейты названы правильно.

@extends('html')

@section('title', 'create')
@section('content')

    <h1>Create service</h1>
    <form action='/service' method='post'>
        <input type='text' name='name'>
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <button>Add service</button>
    </form>
    @error('name') {{ $message }} @enderror

@endsection
```